# How do I create a sliding drawer in code?

Tags: android, set, attributes, slidingdrawer

I'm trying to create a sliding drawer in code, but I don't understand what to do for the AttributeSet part of the constructor.

What do I need to do for that?

Also, how do I define in code where the slider is going to show up?

Thanks,

Comment: SlidingDrawer is already available in Android. Even then if you want to create it, look at the Android implementation.

Comment: I know but I dont' understand how to use this constructor

SlidingDrawer(Context  context, AttributeSet  attrs)

How do you create an attributeset?

Answer (score 7):

SlidingDrawer can't new in Java code because it must define handle and content but you can inflate in XML layout as follows:

sliding_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SlidingDrawer
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/tray_handle_bookmark"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        />
</SlidingDrawer>
```

In Java code:

```
// you main Layout
LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

// add sliding Drawer
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer)inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_drawer, mainLayout, false);
        mainLayout.addView(slidingDrawer);

// get Layout for place your content in sliding drawer
LinearLayout slideContent = (LinearLayout)slidingDrawer.findViewById(R.id.content);

slideContent.addView(.....); // add your view to slideDrawer
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `SlidingDrawer` cannot be created directly in Java code. You will need to define it in an XML layout and inflate that layout.

Sorry!